# When does git pull cause merge between multiple branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-subtree

I'm trying to understand the circumstances that caused git to merge a feature branch I was working on into the main develop branch after switching to the develop branch.

I was able to revert the merge but it took the better part of a day to fully resolve and I'd like to avoid it in the future.

Here is the workflow:

After working on my feature branch I need to work on a bug fix.
My feature branch (refs/heads/feature/uploader/90) has been kept up with the main develop branch with:

```
git merge origin/develop
```

Then I need to switch to the develop branch:

```
git checkout develop
```

git outputs:

*Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 88 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.*

Then when I issue a pull:

```
git pull origin refs/heads/develop
```

For some reason it looks like git has decided to merge my feature branch into develop, the output looks like this:

```
branch develop -> FETCH_HEAD
Fast-forwarding to: 102301bcc51fc6d7978e5287df9d031d82e53bc9
Trying simple merge with d139bab0a96df01408f82110e38b6e0b6b98e6e6
Merge made by the 'octopus' strategy.
```

And my commit log shows me committing:
*Merge branches 'feature/uploader/90' and 'develop' of github.com:MakerStudios/dashboard into develop*

Comment: Did you have a merge in progress between `feature/uploader/90` and `develop` that had not completed due to conflicts needing to be resolved? `git pull` will not usually do an octopus merge - that makes me think it saw a merge in progress plus the newly requested merge (via `git pull`)... If that were the case, though, I would have expected it to complain...

Comment: @twalberg - Good question, to the best of my knowledge I did not have a merge in progress. Most of the merges to feature/uploader/90 were done by another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is known as a *fast-forward merge*.

It happens (by default) any time you do a merge where all the changes in the branch on which you reside are already present in the branch you're trying to merge in.

So, since in your above example `refs/heads/feature/uploader/90` already contained all the changes in `refs/heads/develop`, instead of creating a true merge commit, `git` just moved the ref `develop` to point to the same commit as `feature/uploader/90`.

You can avoid this behavior by doing `git merge --no-ff`, which will not fast-forward, or changing the `merge.ff` property to `false`.

Undoing an undesired fast-forward merge is not as difficult as you make it out to be: just `git reset --hard` to the last commit before the stuff which came in on the merge.

Comment: Thanks for that @Borealid, in my case I could not do a git reset --hard because other people had made changes in develop in the meantime.  I ended up issuing a git revert -m 1 sha_of_merge.

Comment: a fast-forward merge does not create a merge commit and does not merge a second branch in.